# How to set the selected value for react-bootstrap-typeahead

Tags: reactjs, select, react-bootstrap-typeahead

I created an employee form which is divided in to multiple partitions, one of the field in the form is supervisor, i'm using **react-bootstrap-typeahead** to **autocomplete** the supervisor. After selecting the value i'm able to fetch the **selected valu**e but when i use navigation button to go the next part of form(i'm hiding the present partition on click of next button) and again coming back to the previous partition the value is again being empty. I'm unable to understand what i did wrong?

```
<div className = "form-group row col-md-6">
     <label className="col-sm-4 col-form-label">Supervisor: </label>
          <div className = "col-sm-6">
               <Typeahead ref="typeahead"
                 labelKey={option => `${option.firstName} ${option.lastName}`}
                 onChange = {this.supervisorSelected}
                 options= {this.state.supervisorOptions}/>
          </div>
</div>

//onChange function
supervisorSelected(selectedSupervisor){
        console.log(selectedSupervisor);
        if(selectedSupervisor.length != 0){
            this.setState({
            selectedSupervisor : selectedSupervisor[0].employeeId,
        })
        console.log(this.state.selectedSupervisor);    
        }
    }
```

Comment: It's difficult to help without seeing a full code example. My guess based on what you're describing and the code you did post is that navigating resets `this.state.supervisorOptions` so that it's empty when you go back to the first section. Can you post the code that does the navigating?

Comment: Actually navigation in the sense i'm just hiding a part of form and showing other part based on click of a button @ericgio

Comment: I understand that, but if you're mounting/unmounting a component in the course of showing/hiding it, you'd be re-setting the initial state and therefore losing the value. Like I said, however, seeing all the code would be helpful.